# AJAX Return Problem from data sent via jQuery.ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to receive a json object back from php after sending data to the php file from the js file.

All I get is undefined.

Here are the contents of the php and js file.

**data.php**

```
<?php
```

$action = $_GET['user'];

$data = array(  "first_name" => "Anthony",
                "last_name" => "Garand",
                "email" => "anthonygarand@gmail.com",
                "password" => "changeme");

switch ($action) {
    case 'anthonygarand@gmail.com':
        echo $_GET['callback'] . '('. json_encode($data) . ');';
    break;
}

?>

**core.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({    url: "data.php", 
            data: {"user":"anthonygarand@gmail.com"}, 
            context: document.body, 
            data: "jsonp",
            success: function(data){renderData(data);}
            });
```

});

function renderData(data) {
    document.write(data.first_name);
}

Comment: Is the json object undefined or the value of first_name? (Try alerting the data instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two data options set in the Ajax function.  Instead of the line

```
data: "jsonp",
```

You need

```
dataType: "jsonp"
```

As you're not actually passing the PHP file any information.

Another couple of things, make sure you're getting valid JSON (jsonlint.com), we had a similar issue and it turned out we had the wrong kind of quotes.

Lastly: You MAY need to JSON.parse(data) to see convert it to an object at Javascript's end.

Comment: Try FireBug, view the Console tab and see what you're getting posted back